# Dynamically added angular material input not getting styling

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to add Angular Material inputs based on a number the user enters.

```
var inputArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<vm.boxQty; i++)
    {
        inputArray.push("<md-input-container><input type='text'  data-ng-model='vm.trackingNumber'></md-input-container>");
    }
    angular.element('.box-inputs')
    .html(inputArray);
```

But once the inputs are added, they don't get the material styling.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw3ZZ.jpg
How can I add these inputs and get the styling?  Thanks

Comment: If I'm correct, angular compiles your html, so you could use the `$compile` service, or take another approach with an `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding inputs like you are, I recommend using ng-repeat.

So you'd have something like this: I'll explain in a bit what `ng-model='input.val'` is.

```
<div ng-repeat="input in vm.inputs">
      <md-input-container><input type='text'  data-ng-model='input.val'></md-input-container>  
</div>
```

Then, in your controller you will initialize vm.inputs as an array with a single object, with a `val` property like so:

```
vm.inputs = [{
    val: null
}];
```

The `val` property is so you keep track of which input has which value.
Whenever you want to add another input, you just push a new object with a null val in your controller / function, like so:

```
vm.addInput = function () {
        vm.inputs.push({val:null});
 }
```

Of course, you can add as many properties to the input object as you wish, depending on what you need to keep track of for your inputs.

Here's a fiddle putting this all together: http://jsfiddle.net/fnc2m3uc/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was just coming at this problem from the wrong angle.